# Link Error in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, linker, unreal-engine4

*Disclaimer: there is a high chance this is very specific to Unreal Engine, but I haven't got an answer there so I thought I'd try a more general query here. Sorry if this is considered off topic/too specific*

I am getting a link error compiling the following code in Unreal Engine 4:

```
RHISetRenderTarget(TextureRenderTarget->GetRenderTargetTexture(), NULL);
```

This is being called within a macro (`ENQUEUE_UNIQUE_RENDER_COMMAND_TWOPARAMETER`) but the link error happens even if you don't.

The error itself is:

```
MaterialToTextureRenderer.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl RHISetRenderTargets(unsigned int,class FRHIRenderTargetView const *,class FRHITexture *,unsigned int,class FRHIUnorderedAccessView * const *)" (__imp_?RHISetRenderTargets@@YAXIPEBVFRHIRenderTargetView@@PEAVFRHITexture@@IPEBQEAVFRHIUnorderedAccessView@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl RHISetRenderTarget(class FRHITexture *,class FRHITexture *)" (?RHISetRenderTarget@@YAXPEAVFRHITexture@@0@Z)
```

*Compressed for readability:*

```
unresolved external symbol: void RHISetRenderTargets(unsigned int, FRHIRenderTargetView const *,FRHITexture *,unsigned int,FRHIUnorderedAccessView * const *)
referenced in: void RHISetRenderTarget(FRHITexture *,FRHITexture *)
```

(The method the unlinked method is referenced in is the method I am calling).

And 4 other simillar link errors.

I'm not by any stretch of the imagination a C++ expert, but my understanding is a link error is caused when the header file is correctly included but then it can't actual find an implementation of the method to point to.

What I don't understand is, the method whose implementation it can't find, is within the Unreal Engine (which I am assuming doesn't actually have missing method implementations etc!).

Further, both the method I am calling, and the method it is calling (and can't link) are both defined `inline` in the same header file. The only thing I can see that could be wrong is the method that is being used is declared and implemented further down the header file, but I don't believe that could be a problem (certainly not a link problem).

Comment: do you add the .lib file which contains that function?

Comment: I've sort of assumed, since Unreal builds the VS .sln file, it is handling all of that sort of thing. Further, since the actual unlinked method is within the same file as the method that is referencing it, can it still be a missing lib file?

Comment: from the error, could be lib file missing or mismatch.

Comment: If the error was failing to link `RHISetRenderTarget(FRHITexture*,FRHITexture*)` I would accept that, but it is failing to link a method called from within that method. Is it that the compiler hasn't inlined the other method (e.g. too big) so it is only then it is forced to look for the lib?

Comment: Are you including "Runtime/RHI/Public/RHIUtilities.h" in your cpp file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that you include RHI and RenderCore in your .build.cs for your target like this

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "RHI", "RenderCore", "ShaderCore" });
```

Comment: this answer saved me on an unresolved global in render core :)